# iPhone Force Download Files?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iphone, html

I am trying to allow the user to download a file.

When the file is downloaded it is displayed in the browser window instead of downloading it.

Does anyone know of a way to get the iPhone to download files instead of viewing them.

Also all the code that I have tried works great on Android Devices.

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried doc's and jpg's but the list is really unlimited.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Apple have deliberately prevented things like this to protect their iOS from hacks and malware; you have no access (unless you are a developer, in which case its restricted) to the handsets integrated data storage.

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing a program that downloads an image, or trying to do this as a user?

If you're writing a program, you can only download files to a limited number of locations. Your app's documents directory is the most obvious choice.

You will need to create an NSURLRequest, and then an NSURLConnection, and then implement a number of delegate methods to handle the incoming data. Then you'll need to use NSFileManager methods to write the data to a file.